# Use different shading in the same figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, surface, shading

Is it possible to use different `shading` types in the same figure?

For example this code:

```
figure; hold on 
surf(1:10,1:10,repmat(1,10,10),rand(10))
shading flat; hold on
surf(1:10,1:10,repmat(3,10,10),rand(10))
shading flat; hold on
surf(1:10,1:10,repmat(5,10,10),rand(10))
shading interp
view(-15,32)
```

results in:
[image: example]

So that the last `shading` determines the type `interp` for all the objects in the figure.

Is there some work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`'FaceColor'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html#input_argument_d0e975684) is `flat` and [`'EdgeColor'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html#input_argument_d0e975312) is `black` when you use `surf`.
`shading flat` sets the `'FaceColor'` as `'flat'` and  `'EdgeColor'` as `none`.
`shading interp` sets the `'FaceColor'` as `'interp'` and  `'EdgeColor'` as `none`.

So you can specify those properties like this:

```
figure;
surf(1:10,1:10,repmat(1,10,10),rand(10),'EdgeColor','none');
hold on;     %You don't need to use hold on again and again
surf(1:10,1:10,repmat(3,10,10),rand(10),'EdgeColor','none');
surf(1:10,1:10,repmat(5,10,10),rand(10),'FaceColor', 'interp','EdgeColor','none');
view(-15,32);
```

which gives:

[image: output]

or get a handle to each surface plot and change that later as shown in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html#bvgs7wv-1).